# Мне надо редактировать по строкам а не сразу, у меня все строки после onClica становятся активными,и после редактирование icon должен быть FaPen

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/Table.css';
import { FaCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { FaPen } from 'react-icons/fa';

class Table extends Component {
   state = {
      data: [
         { id: 1, name: 'Anna', surname: 'Ananyan', score: 10, isEditMode: false },
         { id: 2, name: 'Alla', surname: 'Balayan', score: 5, isEditMode: false },
         { id: 3, name: 'Vahan', surname: 'Manasyan', score: 15, isEditMode: false },
         { id: 4, name: 'Gor', surname: 'Ayvazyan', score: 20, isEditMode: false }
      ]
   }



onClickPen = (e) => {
   this.setState({
      isEditMode: true,
      score: ""
   })
}

onClickFaCheckCircle = (event) => {
this.setState({
      isEditMode: false,
      score: event.target.value
   })
}


onChange(event){

   this.setState((event) =>{

  return{ score: event.target.value} 
   })
}

renderTableHeader() {
   return (
   <tr id="data">
      <th id="th" classsName="colum">ID</th>
      <th id="th">Name</th>
      <th id="th">Surname</th>
      <th id="th">Score</th>
   </tr>

   );
}

renderTableData() {
    return this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
      const { id, name, surname, score,isEditMode } = data //destructuring
          return (
          <tr key={this.state.index}>
            <td id="td" class="colum">{id}</td>
            <td id="td" >{name}</td>
            <td id="td">{surname}</td>
     {/* <td id ="td" key ={index}>{this.state.isEditMode ? <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange}  /> : <span>{score}</span>}
            {this.state       .isEditMode ? <button  onClick={this.onChange}><FaCheckCircle /></button> : <button  key={id} onClick={this.changeEditMode}><FaPen/></button>}</td> */}
            <td id="td">{this.state.isEditMode ? <input type="text" onChange={(event) =>this.onChange(event)} /> : <span>{score}</span>}

               {this.state.isEditMode ? <button key={this.state.id} onClick={ this.onClickFaCheckCircle}><FaCheckCircle /></button> : <button key={this.state.id} onClick={ this.onClickPen} ><FaPen /></button>}
            </td>
         </tr>
      )
   })
}

render() { 
   return (
      <div>
         <h1 align="center">My Table</h1>
         <table id='data'>
            <tbody>
               {this.renderTableHeader()}
               {this.renderTableData()}
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   )
}
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в стейте массив записей. А вы по нажатию изменяете общий стейт. Вот сразу все поля и срабатывают. Для раздельного редактирования лучше создать еще один компонент, отвечающий за конкретную запись. (иконки добавлял вручную, у себя потом исправите на собственные компоненты)

```js
class Element extends React.Component {
  onEditClick = () => {
    this.props.onEditClick(this.props.recordId);
  }
  
  onSaveClick = () => {
    this.props.onSaveClick(this.props.recordId);
  }
  
  onEditChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onEditChange(this.props.recordId, e.target.value);
  }
  
  renderInput() {
    if(this.props.isEditMode) {
      return (
        <div class="input-group">
          <input 
            type="text" 
            className="form-control" 
            placeholder="score..."
            onChange={this.onEditChange}
            value={this.props.score}
          />
          <span className="input-group-btn">
            <button 
              class="btn btn-primary" 
              type="button"
              onClick={this.onSaveClick}
            >
              <span className="fa fa-check-circle"/>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    return (
      <button 
        className="btn btn-primary" 
        type="button"
        onClick={this.onEditClick}
      >
        <span className="fa fa-pencil"/> <span class="badge">{this.props.score}</span>
      </button>
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.id}</td>
        <td>{this.props.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.surname}</td>
        <td>
          {this.renderInput()}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
   state = {
      data: [
         { id: 1, name: 'Anna', surname: 'Ananyan', score: 10, isEditMode: false },
         { id: 2, name: 'Alla', surname: 'Balayan', score: 5, isEditMode: false },
         { id: 3, name: 'Vahan', surname: 'Manasyan', score: 15, isEditMode: false },
         { id: 4, name: 'Gor', surname: 'Ayvazyan', score: 20, isEditMode: false }
      ]
   }

  onEditClick = (recordId) => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data[recordId].isEditMode = true;
    this.setState({
      data:data
    })
  }

  onSaveClick = (recordId) => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data[recordId].isEditMode = false;
    this.setState({
      data:data
    })
  }


  onEditChange = (recordId, value) => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data[recordId].score = value;
    this.setState({
      data: data
    });
  }

  renderTableHeader() {
     return (
     <tr id="data">
        <th id="th" classsName="colum">ID</th>
        <th id="th">Name</th>
        <th id="th">Surname</th>
        <th id="th">Score</th>
     </tr>

     );
  }

  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
      const { id, name, surname, score,isEditMode } = data //destructuring
      return (
        <Element
          key={id}
          id={id}
          recordId={index}
          name={name}
          surname={surname}
          score={score}
          isEditMode={isEditMode}
          onEditClick={this.onEditClick}
          onSaveClick={this.onSaveClick}
          onEditChange={this.onEditChange}
        />
      )
    });
  }

  render() { 
     return (
        <div>
           <h1 align="center">My Table</h1>
           <table id='data' className="table">
              <tbody>
                 {this.renderTableHeader()}
                 {this.renderTableData()}
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Table/> , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```