# Как сделать редактирование данных в самой таблице React

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs

нужна помощь, сделал небольшое приложение Crud работающее с базой данных, вот есть проблемка, нужно сделать так чтобы редактировать данные можно было в самой таблице (например нажимаю на кнопку `edit` и строка выделялась в таблице и можно было редактировать все поля в строке). На данный момент при нажатии на кнопку редактировать у меня идет перенаправление на страницу с полями `input`, в которые по id вносятся данные. React знаю пока очень плохо, вот ищу помощи у людей которые топчик в этом деле.

Страница с таблицей ListPersonaComponent.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ApiService from "../../ApiService";
import $ from 'jquery';

    class ListPersonaComponent extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                persons: [],
                message: null
            }
            this.deletePersona = this.deletePersona.bind(this);
            this.editPersona = this.editPersona.bind(this);
            this.addPersona = this.addPersona.bind(this);
            this.reloadPersonaList = this.reloadPersonaList.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.reloadPersonaList();
        }

        reloadPersonaList() {
            ApiService.fetchPersons()
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({persons: res.data.result})
                });
        }

        deletePersona(personaId) {
            ApiService.deletePersona(personaId)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({message: 'Persona deleted successfully.'});
                    this.setState({persons: this.state.persons.filter(persona => persona.id !== personaId)});
                })

        }

        editPersona(id) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("personaId", id);
            this.props.history.push('/edit-persona');
        }

        addPersona() {
            window.localStorage.removeItem("personaId");
            this.props.history.push('/add-persona');
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="container mt-4 col-12">
                    <div className="card border-secondary">
                        <div className="card-header bg-secondary text-white">
                            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.addPersona()}><i className="fa fa-plus"
                                                                                                  aria-hidden="true"></i> Add
                                Persona
                            </button>

                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body table-responsive-md">


                            <table className="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                <tr className="bg-secondary text-white text-center">
                                    <th className="d-none">Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Nationality</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                {
                                    this.state.persons.map(
                                        persona =>
                                            <tr key={persona.id}>
                                                <td>{persona.name }</td>
                                                <td>{persona.email}</td>
                                                <td>{persona.nationality}</td>
                                                <td className="text-center">
                                                    <button className="btn btn-md btn-warning"
                                                            onClick={() => this.editPersona(persona.id)}><i
                                                        className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit
                                                    </button>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <button className="btn btn-md btn-danger"
                                                            onClick={() => this.deletePersona(persona.id)}><i
                                                        className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    )
                                }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

    }

export default ListPersonaComponent;
```

Страница где я сейчас редактирую записи EditPersonaComponent.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ApiService from "../../ApiService";

class EditPersonaComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
            nationality: '',
        }
        this.savePersona = this.savePersona.bind(this);
        this.loadPersona = this.loadPersona.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadPersona();
    }

    loadPersona() {
        ApiService.fetchPersonaById(window.localStorage.getItem("personaId"))
            .then((res) => {
                let persona = res.data.result;
                this.setState({
                    id: persona.id,
                    name: persona.name,
                    email: persona.email,
                    nationality: persona.nationality,
                })
            });
    }

    onChange = (e) =>
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

    savePersona = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let persona = {
            id: this.state.id, name: this.state.name, email: this.state.email,
            nationality: this.state.nationality
        };
        ApiService.editPersona(persona)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({message: 'Persona added successfully.'});
                this.props.history.push('/persona');
            });
    }


    backToMain() {
        this.props.history.push('/persona');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container mt-4 col-8">
                <div className="card border-secondary">
                    <div className="card-header bg-secondary text-white">
                        <h2 className="text-center">Edit Persona</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body table-responsive-md">

                        <form>

                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" className="form-control"
                                       readonly="true" defaultValue={this.state.name}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <input placeholder="First Name" name="email" className="form-control"
                                       value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Nationality:</label>
                                <input placeholder="Last name" name="nationality" className="form-control"
                                       value={this.state.nationality} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.savePersona}>Save</button>
                            &nbsp;
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.backToMain()}>Назад</button>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EditPersonaComponent;
```

Comment: Посмотрите, может ваш случай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033419/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-onclica-%d1%81%d1%82/1033522#1033522

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересен вариант решение этой задачи, то вот он:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ApiService from "../../ApiService";
import $ from 'jquery';

class ListPersonaComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            persons: [],
            message: null,
            isEditMode: false,
            id: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
            nationality: '',
        }
        this.deletePersona = this.deletePersona.bind(this);
        this.editPersona = this.editPersona.bind(this);
        this.addPersona = this.addPersona.bind(this);
        this.reloadPersonaList = this.reloadPersonaList.bind(this);
        this.savePersona = this.savePersona.bind(this);
        this.loadPersona = this.loadPersona.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.reloadPersonaList();
    }

    reloadPersonaList() {
        ApiService.fetchPersons()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({persons: res.data.result})
            });
    }

    deletePersona(personaId) {
        ApiService.deletePersona(personaId)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({message: 'Persona deleted successfully.'});
                this.setState({persons: this.state.persons.filter(persona => persona.id !== personaId)});
            })

    }

    loadPersona() {
        ApiService.fetchPersonaById(window.localStorage.getItem("personaId"))
            .then((res) => {
                let persona = res.data.result;
                this.setState({
                    id: persona.id,
                    name: persona.name,
                    email: persona.email,
                    nationality: persona.nationality,
                })
            });
    }

    onChange = (e) =>
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

    savePersona = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let persona = {
            id: this.state.id, name: this.state.name, email: this.state.email,
            nationality: this.state.nationality
        };
        ApiService.editPersona(persona)
            .then(res => {
                this.state.isEditMode = false;
                this.setState({message: 'Persona added successfully.'});

                this.props.history.push('/persona');
                this.reloadPersonaList();
            });
    }

    editPersona(id) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("personaId", id);
        this.state.isEditMode = true;
        this.loadPersona();
        // this.props.history.push('/edit-persona');
    }

    addPersona() {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("personaId");
        this.props.history.push('/add-persona');
    }

    backToMain() {
        this.state.isEditMode = false;
        this.reloadPersonaList();
        this.props.history.push('/persona');
    }

    render() {
        const isChange = this.state.isEditMode;
        return (
            <div className="container mt-4 col-12">
                <div className="card border-secondary">
                    <div className="card-header bg-secondary text-white">
                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.addPersona()}><i className="fa fa-plus"
                                                                                                 aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body table-responsive-md">

                        <table className="table table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr className="bg-secondary text-white text-center">
                                <th className="d-none">Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Nationality</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.persons.map(
                                    persona =>
                                        <tr key={persona.id}>

                                            {isChange && window.localStorage.getItem("personaId") == persona.id ?
                                                <td><input type='text' className='form-control' name="name"
                                                           value={this.state.name}
                                                           onChange={this.onChange}/>
                                                </td> : <td>{persona.name}</td>}


                                            {isChange && window.localStorage.getItem("personaId") == persona.id ?
                                                <td><input type='text' className='form-control' name="email"
                                                           value={this.state.email}
                                                           onChange={this.onChange}/>
                                                </td> : <td>{persona.email}</td>}

                                            {isChange && window.localStorage.getItem("personaId") == persona.id ?
                                                <td><input type='text' className='form-control' name="nationality"
                                                           value={this.state.nationality}
                                                           onChange={this.onChange}/>
                                                </td> : <td>{persona.nationality}</td>}


                                            {isChange && window.localStorage.getItem("personaId") == persona.id ?
                                                <td className="text-center">

                                                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.savePersona}><i
                                                        className="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <button className="btn btn-primary"
                                                            onClick={() => this.backToMain()}><i
                                                        className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td> :
                                                <td className="text-center">

                                                    <button className="btn btn-md btn-warning"
                                                            onClick={() => this.editPersona(persona.id)}><i
                                                        className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <button className="btn btn-md btn-danger"
                                                            onClick={() => this.deletePersona(persona.id)}><i
                                                        className="fa fa-scissors" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                    &nbsp;

                                                </td>
                                            }
                                        </tr>
                                )
                            }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ListPersonaComponent;
```